# How to make an input numeric only?

Tags: jquery, input

I have following html and jquery code (took over from previous co-worker)

```
<div id="div01">
<input type="text" id="txt01" class="NumberMask" maxlength="12"/>
</div>

this.Init=function(){
...
$("#div01").find(".NumberMask").attr("alt", "p0x3p0S").autoNumeric();
...}
```

It works fine. I can only input up to 12 numbers. But if I change maxlength="16", somehow I can only put maximum 15 numbers. Can anyone explain what does this line mean?

```
$("#div01").find(".NumberMask").attr("alt", "p0x3p0S").autoNumeric();
```

and why I can only put 15 instead of 16 numbers?

Comment: I believe what @akinuri is saying is that he/she is on Google Chrome 31 and can input 16 digits just fine in jsfiddle. However, it doesn't include the plugin described in my answer and that's what causing the `maxlength` to change.

Comment: What happens if you add maxlength attribute after adding **.autoNumeric()** to your input field like **$(...).attr('maxlength', '20')**

Comment: I just tested it on my goodl chrome version 31. I still can only input maximum 15 numbers. And to BwithLove, nope, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

`.autoNumeric()` is a jQuery plugin called [autoNumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/).

Depending on it's settings, the plugin will override any `maxlength` you have set. I think it's just a coincidence that the `maxlength` on your `<input>` element was the same as the `maxlength` set by autoNumeric from the start.

`.attr("alt", "p0x3p0S")` just sets the `alt` on your `<input>` to `alt="p0x3p0S"`. This will be the resulting element:

```
<input type="text" id="txt01" alt="p0x3p0S" class="NumberMask" maxlength="12"/>
```

What `p0x3p0S` means I don't know. Possibly some kind of identifier. Need to see the rest of your code to figure that one out, but it most likely has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: just checked, alt="p0x3p0S" will remove the , from 1,23,456,789, that is the result is 123456789.

Comment: Ah, so it too was a part of `.autoNumeric`, interesting. Well there you go then. Do you have your answer? :)

Comment: I still need to know why I can only put 15. Why any other numbers are ok except 16?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, it's this plugin that is overriding your `maxlength`: http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/. You have to read up on the plugin docs and change the settings to match your desired result.

Comment: Look at the setting `vMax` for autoNumeric, which seems to be a good start. It defines the maximum value allowed.

Comment: Or you could always throw out `.autoNumeric` altogether, and replace it with a simpler plugin that limits the input to numeric values, like this one http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

Comment: I tried find(".NumberMask").attr("alt", "p0x3p0S").autoNumeric({ vMax: '10000000000000000' }) but still not working

Answer (score 0):

autoNumeric as of version 1.9.43 completely ignores the html maxlength. Instead it uses its vMax setting as a template for how large a number can be. I believe they do this to accomodate decimal points.

A setting that would be the equivilent to integer only maxlength 5 would be:
vMax: 99999,
vMin: 0,
aSep: ''

explantation: the vMax allows for five characters and removes the decimal points. the vMin set to zero makes sure one of the character spaces will never be a minus sign for negative numbers. The aSep set to nothing ('') makes sure it doesn't inject commas for easy reading large numbers.

I had a similar problem once and had to build a small function that created the vMax setting by getting the elements maxlength and creating a string with that many nines and then setting the autonumeric with that string. But that was a unique case where the application was autogenerating html and javascript bindings dynamically and I had to make it respect the maxlength attribute. You can just set it in the jquery most likely for that object.